# Javascript how to check if my mouse is out of an element and everything inside it

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have this code:

```
<div id="check-div">
    <span>
        <!-- Can be some inside elements here too -->
    </span>

    <!-- Can be more elements here as well ... -->
</div>
```

How can I check if I'm outside of the div `check-div` and everything inside it?

so if for example my mouse will be on the `<span>` inside or anything else inside, the code won't be active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event) event:

> The `mouseleave` event is fired at an Element when the cursor of a pointing device (usually a mouse) is moved out of it.

**Demo:**

```js
var el = document.querySelector('#check-div');
el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {   
  // highlight the mouseleave target
  event.target.style.color = "red";

  // reset the color after a short delay
  setTimeout(function() {
    event.target.style.color = "";
  }, 1000);
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="check-div">
    <span>
        Can be some inside elements here too 
    </span>
    <br/>
    Can be more elements here as well ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event) event here, as `mouseleave` is only fired when the pointer has exited the element and all of its descendants. So, you can be sure that it will be only triggered when outside of the div `check-div` and everything inside it.

```js
function mouselog(event) {
  let d = new Date();
  console.log(`${event.type} [target: ${event.target.id}]\n`) 
}
```

```css
#parent {
  background: #99C0C3;
  width: 160px;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

#child {
  background: #FFDE99;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" onmouseleave="mouselog(event)">parent
    <div id="child">child</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```js
            $("#check-div").mouseover(function(){
            $("#check-div").css("background-color", "yellow");
            });
            
             $("#check-div").mouseout(function(){
             $("#check-div").css("background-color", "red");
             });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="check-div" >
      <span>
        Can be some inside elements here too 
      </span>
      <br/>
      Can be more elements here as well ...
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouseout listener on your window then check if the target is the div you are targeting or one of its children.

The code below explains the scenario

```
var check_div = document.querySelector('#check-div');
window.addEventListener('mouseout', event => {
    if (event.target == check_div || 
         Array.from(check_div.children).includes(event.target)) {
        console.log(true, 'mouse out');
    } else {
        console.log(false, 'mouse in');
    }
});
```

Or you can use the mousedown listener on your window to handle the click behavior.

The code below shows how you can do it

```
var check_div = document.querySelector('#check-div');
window.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
    if (event.target == check_div || 
      Array.from(check_div.children).includes(event.target)) {
        console.log(false, 'div clicked');
    } else {
        console.log(true, 'outside div clicked');
    }
});
```

I was about to forget this, you can as well handle the hover state with mousemove listener.

The below code shows how.

```
var check_div = document.querySelector('#check-div');
window.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
    if (event.target == check_div || 
      Array.from(check_div.children).includes(event.target)) {
        console.log(false, 'mouse on div');
    } else {
        console.log(true, 'mouse outside div');
    }
});
```

Happy coding.....